# How to create correct .css for Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

In my views, I need to have a textboxs with propher style.

For example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number, new {disabled = "disabled", @class = "special-container"})
```

And in .css:

```
.special-container
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #656565 50%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #656565 50%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#ffffff, #656565 50%);
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #656565 50%);
    border-left:1px solid #000000;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    color: red;
    width:90%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Half of it are working. I mean, border and backgroud are working as it supposed to work, **BUT color, font and width gets totally ignored and I can't figure out why**.
If I add, for example, color as atribute or anything that was ignored:

```
Style = "color:red"
```

It's working as it should.

So, my question is, what am I doing wrong if style in .css are ignoring half of properties, but they still works as atributes? How it supposed to look?

P.S Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you checked that there is nothing that overrides this style?

Comment: Inspect the element with your browser console (dev tools) and check the CSS rules applied to it.

Comment: One trick might be to try *temporarily* adding !important to each style which isn't being applied as you expect to see if it is being overridden elsewhere.

Comment: Yep... !important shows that they are overridden... but how to figure out what and why the hell? (Only by F12 in browser?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is something which is overriding your CSS. Please double check on this.

Comment: Yep, looks like something are overriding it bus cant figure out what, Is there a way to make my .css style primary in this case, without !important?

Comment: Find out what overriding it but still don't know how to give my style priority (can't change other one).